# Skip default scope for relation in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, mongoid4

How can I skip the default scope for relations in mongoid?

The trashable concern implements a soft-delete on the model, also it adds the following

```
field :d_at, type: DateTime
default_scope -> { where(d_at: nil) }
```

If a brand gets trashed I still want to have it available when I load a product that has a reference to that brand
These are the model definitions

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  belongs_to :brand, class_name: 'Brand'
end

class Brand
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Concerns::Trashable
  field :title, type: String
end
```

Example:

```
product = Product.find([id])
puts product.brand.inspect #This brand is soft-deleted and not fetched because of the default scope
```

This works, but it breaks more then it fixes

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  belongs_to :brand, class_name: 'Brand'

  #unscope relation to brand
  def brand 
    Brand.unscoped.find(self.brand_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: `Product.unscoped` should return all Product records without applying any scope

Comment: But that would remove the default scope from the Product model right?. Not the scope from the relation between product and brand.

Comment: What about `Brand.unscoped.where(product_id: product.id)` ?

Comment: That would work, but in that way i have to handle relations manual and change the whole codebase to retrieve relations so that isn't an option

Comment: That is because you should not use `default_scope` : http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil

Comment: Still going to use the default scope because it isn't that evil in the current situation (better then writing  Brand.without_deletes.all)

Comment: This is the only case when using soft-deletes because you don't want to explict define that you want to load only non deleted stuff but rather the otherway arround

Answer (score 5):

According to the the fix [***Support unscoping default_scope in eager_loaded associations***](https://github.com/cwjenkins/rails/commit/5884821bc3b4394a9b582d9f7d9fffbe076957b6), you can skip the default scope manually by specifying the columns to be ignored in your association.

```
-> { unscope(where: :column_name) }
```

---

Or you may use [unscoped_associations](https://github.com/markets/unscoped_associations).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work here with mongoid, I need to dig deeper into it and going to play with it

Comment: Apparently it works only with `has_many`. I was not able to make it function with `belongs_to`.

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 It's been a while but were you able to solve this? I ran into the same issue.